# Concatenate Visualforce Component inside Javascript

Tags: visualforce

I need concatenate something like this:

`function teste(index) {
   var val = document.getElementById("{!$Component:form:"+index+":banco}").value;
   alert(val);
}`
But this generates a error of compilation;
Any help is helpful. 
Regards !

Comment: You can not really apply VF markup in real time -- those are defined on page load only. Please, rephrase your question about what you want to achieve, and then another solution would appear (probably)

Answer (score 1):

The `{! }` expressions are evaluated on the server resulting in fixed text in the HTML page that is sent to the client. JavaScript then runs in the client working on that fixed text.

You might be able to get the Id value correct (check using your browser's "Inspect" feature) with something like:

```
var val = document.getElementById("{!$Component:form}" + ':' + index + ":banco").value;
```

But alternative approaches are to use meaningful Id values everywhere in the apex tags so your Javascript can hard code those:

```
var val = document.getElementById("p:f:pb:pbt:" + index + ":banco").value;
```

or use CSS classes as markers instead (that Visualforce doesn't modify) which works best if you also use jQuery so that operations work on many matches at once.